# NameError: name 'ConnectionRefusedError' is not defined

Tags: python, sockets, sh

The following code is throwing me an exception and stopping even with the exception predicted. The code is started via a .sh, which is also printing a log information about the code execution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

# Imports
import socket
from threading import Thread
import struct
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import sys
from time import sleep

# Main Loop

    while True:

    try:

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
        s.settimeout(5)

        while True:

            try:

                # Data Sent 
                MESSAGE = str(""+ gpws_test() +""+ gpws_inhi() +"\r\n")

                s.send(MESSAGE.encode(encoding='utf_8'))
                data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

                # If Recieved Data
                if data == b'': break

                # Translate Byte
                data = data.decode('utf-8')
                data = data.split(',')

                # Board Functions
                gpws_inhi()
                gpws_test()
                start_switch(data)
                power()

                # print ("received data:", data)
                sleep(0.3)

                except ConnectionAbortedError: break

        except (socket.timeout, ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionResetError, OSError) as e:

            print ("No Connection - ", e)   
            sleep(1)

        s.close()

    else:

        GPIO.output(23, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
```

The code initially runs fine, but after a time, it crashes throwing me the following error:

```
except (socket.timeout, ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionResetError, OSError) as e:
NameError: name 'ConnectionRefusedError' is not defined
```

**UPDATE**

When stating a python script via a .sh file, remember to specify the python version:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/user/Desktop/main.py &> /home/user/Desktop/startup.log
```

So as in the begining of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: Raspberry uses both 2.5 and 3.7. I realy not sure about which one he is running.

Comment: How to force a specific version to start?

Comment: Find out, because I don't think ` ConnectionRefusedError` is supported on 2.5 (not certain because I don't have that version).

Comment: To force a specific version, use the `#!` line - that's the problem with using `env`, it depends on your user's `PATH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ConnectionRefusedError` is a built-in exception in Python 3. There is no corresponding built-in exception in Python 2. That is why you are getting the `not defined` error: the name isn't defined.